# Select different source ip address to different destination address

Tags: windows, networking

My server is configured to have two ip address in the same `NIC`, let's say `a.a.a.a` and `b.b.b.b`.
Is it possible to configure it to let's say if there is any outgoing request to `10.0.0.0` , use `b.b.b.b` as source ip address, for any other request, use `a.a.a.a` as source ip address?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got this resolved by setting up NAT in the router to separate destination address.
If you're using Mikrotik as myself, you can refer to their docs

http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/Firewall/NAT